# GO - How does an implicit method work?

Tags: pointers, go, methods, structural-typing

> In GO, I learnt that,
>
> 1)
>
> Programmer can only define methods on named types(`X`) or pointer(`*X`) to named types
>
> 2)
>
> An explicit method definition for type `X` implicitly defines the same method for type `*X` and *vice versa*, so, my understanding is, If I declare,
>
> ```
> func (c Cat) foo(){
>   //do stuff_
> }
> ```
>
> and declare,
>
> ```
> func (c *Cat) foo(){
>   // do stuff_
> }
> ```
>
> then GO compiler gives,
>
> `Compile error: method re-declared`
>
> which indicates that, pointer method is implicitly defined and *vice versa*

---

> With the given named type(`Cat`),
>
> ```
> type Cat struct{
>   Name string
>   Age int
>   Children []Cat
>   Mother *Cat
> }
> ```

---

> **Scenario 1**
>
> Method(`foo`) defined on a named type(`Cat`), by programmer,
>
> ```
> func (c Cat) foo(){
>    // do stuff....
> }
> ```
>
> that implicitly defines method(`foo`) on pointer(`*Cat`) to named type, by GO compiler, that looks like,
>
> ```
> func (c *Cat) foo(){
>    // do stuff....
> }
> ```
>
> On creating variables of named type(`Cat`)
>
> ```
> var c Cat
> var p *Cat = &c
> ```
>
> `c.foo()` has the method defined by programmer.
>
> **Question 1:**
>
> On invoking `p.foo()`, does implicit pointer method receive the pointer(`p`)?

---

> **Scenario 2**
>
> Method(`foo`) defined on a pointer(`*Cat`) to named type, by the programmer,
>
> ```
> func (c *Cat) foo(){
>    // do stuff....
>   }
> ```
>
> that implicitly defines method(`foo`) on named type(`Cat`), by the GO compiler, that looks like,
>
> ```
> func (c Cat) foo(){
>    // do stuff....
>   }
> ```
>
> On creating variables of named type(`Cat`)
>
> ```
> var c Cat
> var p *Cat = &c
> ```
>
> `p.foo()` has method defined by programmer(above).
>
> **Question 2:**
>
> On invoking `c.foo()`, does the implicit non-pointer method receive the value `c`?

Comment: I expect that you get the type the method expects. But why didn't you try it, to see if the struct changes or not after you modify it in a pointer method?

Comment: @ZanLynx I tried, my observation says, **1)** the implicit pointer method receives the pointed to value, but not pointer. **2)** the implicit pointer method receives the pointer to the value, but not the value. *This is bit confusing for me, on understanding, why it is happening in opposite way? Logically it should be as mentioned in the question 1 & 2*

Comment: I consider below answer from @dev.bmax as partially incorrect. Rest is yours

Comment: See my updated answer (reference included).

Answer (score 5):

1. `An explicit method definition for type X implicitly defines the same method for type *X and vice versa.`

This is not correct. Methods are not defined implicitly. The only thing that a compiler does for you is implicitly replacing `c.foo()` with `(*c).foo()` or `c.foo()` with `(&c).foo()` for convenience. See the [tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/6)

2. The receiver of the method is either of type T or of type *T, based on your explicit declaration.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134311/discussion-on-answer-by-dev-bmax-go-how-does-an-implicit-method-work).